# SSIS FTP Task Sending Files to Wrong Directory

Tags: ssis, ftp

I'm using the FTP Task in SSIS to send files. They task succeeds but the files get uploaded to the wrong folder. Instead of being sent to the cg268301 folder they are being sent to the cg268300 despite selecting /cg268301 from the remote path field in the FTP task editor.

I've tried uploading this file to the /cg268301 file using an execute process task and it works fine. I just don't know why it won't work with the FTP task.

Comment: Is there an Expression on the FTP Task? That's about the only reason I can think of for the upload to go anywhere other than what you think you've specified. Install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com] {free tool} and it'll adorn your package with some coloring to indicate that is controlled via expressions and configurations. Very handy

Comment: Thanks for the tool. There are no expressions on the FTP task.

Comment: It was actually some bug and an update was applied which solved the problem.